# Weird a+label+input interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, label, anchor

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('a').click(function(e) {
    console.log('a clicked');
    if ($('.is_force:checked').length) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('input').click();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('label[for]').click(function(e) {
    console.log('label clicked');
});

$('input[id]').click(function(e) {
    var $input = $(this);
    //if ($input.is('[type=radio]')) $input.prop('checked', 'checked');
    console.log('input clicked', $input.is(':checked'));
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            console.log($input.is(':checked'));
        },
        0
    );
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input class="is_force" type="checkbox"> Force checkbox/radio click when clicking on link</label>
<br>
<br>

<div>
    <input id="c" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="c">
        Text
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </label>
</div>

<br>

<div>
    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
    <label for="r1">
        Text
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="r2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
    <label for="r2">
        Text
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

---

Open you console to see the output.

When you click on checkbox/radio, everything works as intended.

It works as intended when you click on labels also.

But, when you click on a link inside a label: link clicks, label clicks, but input associated with the label does not get clicked.

You can "fix" this by programmatically clicking associated input from inside link click handler. To see this in action, check the top checkbox.

The fix works OK for checkboxes. But does not for radios: inside input click handler, the first console.log() shows that clicked radio is not checked. But the second console.log() from inside setTimeout() shows that it actually is checked.

This again can be "fixed" by checking the radio programmatically - see the commented line inside input click handler. But that gets way too hacky.

---

I have a few questions about this:

1. Why corresponding input doesn't get clicked when a link inside a label is clicked?
2. Can this be fixed "the right way" without hacky programmatic clicks?
3. Why radio input "checks" with a delay, while a checkbox works OK?
4. How to fix this without even more hacky "checked" property setting?

Comment: On your checkbox with `Text Link`, clicking the link, I can see it ticking the tickbox then immediately unticking it.  So it's firing the event twice rather than not at all.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I doubt it: if the event fired twice, we would see "a clicked", "label clicked", "input clicked" messages twice too.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I was expecting to see console in the snippet so didn't notice it in browser.  Clicking `Link` as part of `Text Link`, I get two events in the Chrome browser console:a clicked js:44 label clicked js:52.  So yes, the visual effect that I can physically see corresponds to two events in the console.

Comment: To answer your question: it's not `preventDefault` that you want, but likely `e.stopPropagation`.  The anchor event is firing, with prevent default (so doesn't redirect to '#') but is still propagating to the label[for].  With `stopPropagation` in the `a` handler, the `label[for]` doesn't get the event.   So you only get `a clicked` in the console (and nothing happens to the checkbox as you prevent default)

Comment: A quick search in SO shows contradictory issues - some complain the link does tick (mostly older questions) and some complain it does not.  So looks like it's browser (and version) specific).  example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098269/how-to-prevent-checkbox-check-when-clicking-on-link-inside-label

Comment: I'm using FF 52, Chrome 57, IE 11 - with same results. I'm not very familiar with SO editor, I was not sure what to do with snippet console. If you see these two events: "a clicked js:44 label clicked js:52" - this means that corresponding input doesn't get clicked, it remains unchanged. Anyway, if an input is activated twice somehow, then in case of radiobutton it should become checked, which doesn't happen. I cannot use stopPropagation(), because I need to keep links but prevent them from working - it's a requirement from SEO guy. Click on link should work like click on usual text of label.